# Kubernetes job scheduling using work queue

Tags: cron, kubernetes, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, kubernetes-mesos

We are writing a package delivery tracker application using Kubernetes/go-lang. Everything's fine until we've reached a road block where we have certain scheduling needs, and couldn't figure out what to use. The use case is:

1. Once a package is assigned and out for delivery, its location should be tracked.
2. If the package is not assigned after 3 hours of reaching the warehouse, we should mark it as "delivering tomorrow".
3. Some usual cron-type jobs.

for #1 we are planning to schedule a job which will poll the location of package after every 10 seconds. But this is a one time job. Once the package has been delivered. It should die out.

for #2 we are planning to schedule a timed/cron job which will be triggered by our API. This job will be scheduled for 3 hours after the receipt of package at warehouse.

Our #3 above is a usual cron-job for various internal purposes.

We want to use a single scheduling platform to serve all these type of requirements.

Since we are using Kubernetes exclusively, we want to leverage it's job scheduling functionality. But we have certain doubt about it.

1. Can we create these jobs from our source code ? It is possible as mentioned [here](https://github.com/samuell/k8s-experiments/blob/0ada4a53c9e19d29f129960b5d278afe99cdb67f/k8sexp.go#L43-L90). But I am not sure whether our system administrator would allow us to do that.
2. I've read about work queues in Kubernetes, where we can push our jobs to a work queue and a consumer will create jobs for these work items.

   But, I am unaware of how to create a permanent consumer daemon for that work queue, which will poll that queue and create jobs for each work item.

   Another doubt is how to schedule simple cron jobs(#3 above) here.

I've also heard about [Kala](https://github.com/ajvb/kala), but not sure how will this fit in Kubernetes world.

Any reference, pointers, links or suggestions would be highly appreciated as I am pretty new to Kubernetes/Golang in general, and not finding anything concrete on google as well.

Answer (score 1):

How many packages are there?  How important are the time intervals you mention?  There are several approaches that come to mind:

**Kubernetes [cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)** can run on a schedule, and presumably solve your third need.  If you have "some" packages (I wouldn't necessarily try this with more than "hundreds") then for each package you could create a new cron job which runs once then deletes itself.  Cron jobs can't run more often than once a minute.  If you can relax your "poll once every 10 seconds" requirement to "poll once a minute" and the number of packages is small, you could do everything this way.

For the second requirement, you can **check every package for expiration on an interval**.  This works better if the "after 3 hours" requirement isn't particularly strict.  Write a program that looks at *every* package, and if the three-hour delay has passed, changes its state, then write a cron job that runs this every 15 minutes.  The scaling issues around this are different, but "find expired packages" sounds like a single SQL query; it depends on your backend technology.

You can write **one long-running program that does all of the interval-based checks**.  You hint at using Go, and you can set up a `time.Timer` that triggers every 10 seconds (either one for the entire program, or one per package).  I would probably have the program know, in memory, each package ID, its current state, and when it needs to change state to "delivering tomorrow", and run all of this in a single process.  An ordinary Deployment would manage this.  You should also keep this state in a database, and that might introduce some scaling limits.

Finally, you can **use a message queueing system**.  [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com) is a popular open-source choice for this.  You can arrange for messages to be delayed (send a message to exchange `package.in` that routes to a queue `package.wait` with a [TTL](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) of 10 seconds, set that queue's [dead-letter exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) to `package.ready`, send that to a queue `package.out`, and have applications consume from that queue).  Again you'd write a long-running process; this one gets items from the queue, retrieves their state from the database, polls for their current location, and marks them as "delivered tomorrow" or requeues them in `package.in` as appropriate.  This is the most scalable answer (you can launch many workers via a Kubernetes Deployment) but also makes the least use of inbuilt Kubernetes parts.

Comment: Our scaling requirement is not that huge. We would not get past 200 packages for now.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use message queue for job type 1 and 2, and usual cron job for job type 3 ? For type 2 above, If I use RabbitMQ, would I be pushing these jobs in queue after 3 hours or the message will be put in queue immediately but will be consumed after 3 hours ? Similarly for type 1 above, would we be pushing the job immediately to the queue ? and every go routine will poll the location after sleeping for 10 seconds ? Do you have any resources I can follow to implement this dead letter exchange in Kafka/Redis ?

Comment: (3) If you have something where your best description of it is "routine cron job", then a Kubernetes CronJob is probably a good match for it.

Comment: On (1) and (2), if you have a job that runs every 10 seconds until the package is delivered, then it will run after 3 hours if the package isn't delivered yet.  So a couple of my solutions combine these.  In particular my description of the RabbitMQ setup basically only has a single queue where messages get delivered after a 10-second delay that does both halves.  You could implement a similar queue with a 3-hour delay if you wanted.  The RabbitMQ broker itself implements the delay (via the TTL/DLX trick) and the job would continuously consume messages as they become ready.

Comment: You can implement a simple job queue on Redis easily enough, especially if you use a sorted set where the "scores" are the Unix timestamps when the job needs to next execute.  Kafka isn't quite designed for a pattern like this: you can't add delays or message requeueing like RabbitMQ provides, and you can't selectively refuse messages (what happens if polling a specific package's location fails?).  At the scale you describe, any basic database-backed system would work fine and if I was doing it I'd use PostgreSQL, mostly out of personal preference.